# Does the syntax $\sum_{n \geq 1}$ mean the same thing as $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is the syntax $\sum_{n \geq 1}$ equivalent to $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}$?
Is it just another way of writing the same thing?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: One of my teachers used to write $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ to denote the series as a "formal object" and $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1}$ to denote its value (if defined). But I don't know if this habit is widely-spread.

Comment: @Math-fun okay! Thank you. For some reason my brain saw the inequality and thought that it meant that the series could START at anything larger than or equal to 1. So starting at 2 since 2 is greater than 1. I didn’t see that it meant n will count to any value greater than or equal to 1, ie infinity.

Comment: In my opinion, one should never use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ before having proved that the series is convergent : it denotes a number, and you have to prove that this number exists before writing it. Whereas the notation $\sum_{n \geq 1}$ is more ambiguous and may denote the object "series", even if you don't know if it converges or diverges.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is: it depends. It might mean the same thing, but some people would see a difference, which can be important in some situations.

About a given $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$, a sequence of real numbers, one can say different things:

- the sequence ("of partial sums") $\left(\sum^n_{i=1} u_i\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent; one usually says that *the series* (associated to the sequence) *converges*;
- the *value* of the series is some real number (i.e. the limit of the above sequence of partial sums);
- the sequence is *summable* and the value of the sum is some real number (to be defined below).

For pedagogical purposes, it might be worthwhile to forbid students to write things whose existence has not been previously shown. For example, some teachers don't like things like

> $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt{1+\frac{1}{n}} = 1$ so the sequence $(\frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges

because one shouldn't write $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n+1}}{\sqrt{n}} = \cdots$ before having proved that the sequence is convergent.

Something like

> the series $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} u_n$ is convergent and $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} u_n = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$"

would also be weird, since the same notation $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} u_n$ is used to denote two different things in the same sentence: the series as an object in itself and its value. In other words, if we replace $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} u_n$ by $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ in the above sentence, we get

> the series $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ is convergent

which is definitely weird.

For this reason, one of my teachers used to prefer the notation $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ to denote the series in itself, and $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}$ to denote the value of this series, once it has been proved to be convergent. The $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}$ notation for the value of a series, is, I think, quite universal; but I'm not sure about the notation $\sum_{n\geq 1}$.

The story could end here without further worries if you haven't heard of summable families or Lebesgue integration... But if you have, there is something else that can be denoted in a similar way and could produce another confusion.

Let $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ be a sequence of, let's say, real numbers. The notation $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} u_n$ refers to (if it exists) the only real number $S$ such that for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists $J \subset \mathbb{N}^*$ finite such that for every finite subset $J'$ of $\mathbb{N}^*$ containing $J$, we have $\vert \sum_{n \in J'} u_n - S \vert < \epsilon$.

If $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} u_n$ exists, the sequence $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*}$ is said to be **summable**. Like S.K. mentioned it in his/her answer, this is equivalent to say that the function $ u : \mathbb{N}^* \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue-integrable, with respect to the counting measure.

One can, in fact, show that a sequence of real numbers is summable if and only the series associated to it is absolutely convergent.

So, for a convergent but not absolutely convergent series, $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} u_n$ exists (it is the value of the series) but $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}^*} u_n$ does not.

All that said, my advice would be: if you are a student, ask the teacher to tell you exactly what notation choices he/she makes and, when writing an exam, give precisions on what your notations refer to.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the downvotes...

Comment: Hah, thanks for the upvotes :D

Comment: You're right: this is'nt really relevant. People noticing or not noticing notwithstanding.

Comment: To my knowledge, the notation $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n = s$ means that $a_n$ is convergent to $s$, while otherwise you say that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}a_n$ does not exist. Therefore, unterstanding $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ as the limit of its partial sums, writing $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ implies that the series is convergent with the given limit. And I don't know what a "formal series" should be in this context, the series of partial sums?

Comment: In any case, I think this answer is relevant. At least it shows to the person who asked that there is no common agreement on what $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ means and it might be dangerous to use the symbol synonymously with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$, since it might lead to confusion.

Comment: For me, the "formal object" representing the series is the sequence of partial sums, yes. I agree with the rest :)!

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ coincide if $(a_n)$ is absolutely convergent. The first symbol means "integration w.r.t. the counting measure", i.e. is defined as $$ \sum_{n\geq 1} a_n = \sup_{S \subset \mathbb{N}, |S| < \infty } \sum_{s \in S} \max(a_s,0) - \sup_{S \subset \mathbb{N}, |S| < \infty } \sum_{s \in S} \max(-a_s,0) $$ while the second symbol means
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n. $$

The first symbol is not defined for some series, e.g. $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, because its positive and negative parts may both (!) be separately divergent, so we would get $\infty-\infty$. The advantage here is that the notation can be extended to arbitrary sets, even uncountable ones, e.g. $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x)$ makes sense for some $f$, namely those for which there are either at most countably many negative or positive terms and whose sum converges.

On the other hand, we have $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = -\log(2)$. The important point is that both definitions agree for absolutely convergent sequences. In this case the summation order is immaterial. The first definition has the advantage, that one can use Fubini's theorem to justify the exchange of summation order, etc.

EDIT: The above convention for $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ is non-standard and depends on the field/context in question.

Comment: Your usage of $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ is certainly not universal (I, for one, have never encountered this particular usage of it)

Comment: @Wojowu Sure, there are many ways to define a symbol. Maybe even some people use the two symbols synonymously. I suppose that it depends on the context in which they are used. What would be your definition for $\sum_{n\geq 1}$?

Comment: To me $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ is exactly synonymous to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$. Others in the comments suggest yet another interpretation (as "formal sum" vs "actual value of the sum"). I'm not saying either is more correct than the other, just acknowledging not everyone means the same (while your answer makes it sound like yours is the only meaning).

Comment: Yes, I agree. The ambiguity in the notation $\sum_{n \geq 1}$ is the implicit summation order. For example, any series that is summable as in the other answer, has also the same limit value as in my both definitions. In my opinion, the notation $\sum_{n\geq 1}$ should be avoided because it can lead to confusion, unless it is unconditionally convergent. For example, for you, what does the following mean: $\sum_{n\geq m} a_{n,m}$?

Comment: Why all the downvotes?

Comment: +1 and strongly agree, though I feel this is usually unstated

Comment: Interesting. Do you recall any books/sources which employ this definition?